# How to rotate a Widget around a focal point using gestures in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

In Flutter, I can rotate a Widget using the Transform Widget. However, the rotation is around origin specified in the Transform widget properties rather than around the current focal point.

I tried modifying the Matrix by translating to the focal point, rotating, and then translating back.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: new TransformContainer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TransformContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  const TransformContainer({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TransformContainerState createState() {
    return new TransformContainerState();
  }
}

class TransformContainerState extends State<TransformContainer> {
  Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (details) {
            matrix.translate(-details.globalPosition.dx, -details.globalPosition.dy);
            matrix.rotateZ(0.174533);
            matrix.translate(details.globalPosition.dx, details.globalPosition.dy);
            setState(() {});
          },
          onDoubleTap: () {
            setState(() {
              matrix = Matrix4.identity();
            });
          },
          child: Transform(
            transform: matrix,
            alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black54,
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 320,
                  height: 320,
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 64.0,
          right: 64.0,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
              iconSize: 72.0,
              color: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  matrix = Matrix4.identity();
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When you run the code and tap on the screen, the Widget is rotated around the origin. How can I make it rotate around the tap position?

Comment: tried `leftTranslate`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: first call `matrix.translate(` with positive values, rotate and call `matrix.translate(` with negative values - it helps a bit, but still there is something wrong: - think the culprit is in `globalPosition` - you need some `"localPosition"`

Comment: Global position here is fine, because the Widget is full-screen. But yeah, there is something wrong with this.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

Set the transform origin as **center** before applying rotation on the widget;

```
alignment: FractionalOffset.center
```

Comment: Setting alignment to center would make the Widget rotate around center - not around the focal point.

Comment: When you say "focal point", I understand it as "center". What do you mean with focal ?